# Terminal icon disappearing after uninstalling packages?

Tags: command-line, 16.04, icons, icon-themes

I was going on a hard drive purging spree by uninstalling software that I don't really use anymore, and by using the command 'sudo apt-get purge atom' the icon for my terminal disappeared. What I want to know is, how do I get it back? BTW, I am using the default DE that comes with Ubuntu 16.04 LTS and I have freshly uninstalled my previous default icon theme, the paper icon theme as well as the flatabulous icon theme, but neither of those uninstallations cause this problem.

Comment: I don't think this is a duplicate question because my situation is different, also I have seen that question and tried the accepted answer to no avail

Comment: Obviously, atom removed what is not (only) his. An idea would be to reinstall atom, see if the icons are back and see what icons it installs from `dpkg -L atom`